# jQuery 2 level hover navigation and mouseovers/mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, hover, fadeout

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Tvu/

I have 2 `UL`s, each filled with `LI`s.  When I hover over `.nav-dayselector ul li a`, jQuery is being used to show the corresponding `#hover-days ul li` in the second `UL` (this is necessary because the actual code is used inside a carousel with `overflow:hidden` on , so we need to use 2 separate `UL` and show them this way.

This works fine - the issue is that when you hover over the `span` that pops up (`#hover-days ul li span`), the `#hover-days ul li` fades out.  (see the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Tvu/))

I need to stop this `fadeOut` while the mouse is over the span, so that you can use the menu and select items from the `:hover span`.

Any other way of doing this that works with the 2 separate `UL`s would be perfectly fine, though.  Any simple fix on the jsfiddle that would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you keep a reference to the element you can
tell it to stop fading out when its hovered over
but this requiers the user to reach it with the mousepointer before
its faded out

```
  $(".nav-dayselector ul li a").each(function() {
    IndexLI = $(this).parent().index();
    var ele = $("#hover-days ul li:eq("+IndexLI+") span");

    $(this).hover(function() {
     ele.show();
    }, function() {
     ele.fadeOut();
    });

    ele.hover(function() {
     $(ele).stop().fadeIn();
    }, function() {
     $(ele).fadeOut();
    });
  });
```

the html/css dosent seem to be working in my browser btw (IE 8)